# Firebase cloud notification HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, firebase, firebase-notifications

I need to create an HTML pages which send notification to every android devices (which have installed a specific app). I can do this in the Firebase control panel but I need to improve this function in an HTML page. How should I do the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually just recently adding a similar functionality to my own project. So one thing that took me far to long to realize was, you can't simply do the same thing as in the console where you send to all devices on the app. So what you need to do is make a topic like "android" and subscribe your app to that topic (note that this may take a few hours to complete as topics get added super slowly). In your FirebaseInstanceIDService:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your topic");
```

Next, you can follow the guide on the firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message). A few things I did that seemed to work for me:

1) Send to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send instead of the link with your project name in it.

2) For authorization, use Authorization:key=your server key that you can find in settings

3) Use the to paramater to send to your topic.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To make & subscribe to a topic is ok to directly call FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android")
?

Comment: Yep! That's what you'd wanna call. Just remember it takes some time for a topic to be added. So it might not show up for a bit.